# Adding two numbers,by two decimal precision

Tags: php, math, pdo

My PHP Application is getting to the PDO query numbers like this:

```
Number A is 95199.60 from $_POST['num_a']
Number B is 21895.91 from $_POST['num_b']
```

The result should be 117095.51 but in the database it occurs 117095.5
However, in the same query Number A in the database is 95199.6 and number B is 21895.91 - so the first number got one decimal precision and the second got two decimal precision. Anyway, my system cannot handle that and still round the result of A and B to one decimal precision but this is not a valid result.

I've tried using simple adding plus symbol and also sprintf function but with no results. Structure for the result field in the database was previously float, now i've changed for a test reason to the varchar and it's still the same like before. Anyone could help with that?

Comment: It would be great if you could provide Table schema

Comment: Number A - varchar(8), number B - varchar(8), Result varchar(8) - previously everything was to float

Comment: _“so the first number got one decimal precision and the second got two decimal precision”_ - that is incorrect phrasing. A real _number_ does not have any trailing zeroes - that is a matter of _formatting_ the data when you output it, not of how the data is stored. And using VARCHAR for numeric values is rather nonsense. You probably want to use DECIMAL.

Comment: @CBroe i'm not outputing any data. I'm logged into the database and see the results there..

Comment: So, what’s your point? In the database it _should_ be `95199.6` only, because as I said, _storing_ numeric values with trailing zeroes after the decimal point does not make sense.

Comment: The data types in the database should be decimal 7,2 or higher depending on how large the numbers might be.

Comment: @CBroe , i want a result to be a valid. 95199.6 its not a problem. Look - Number A is 95199.6. Number B is 21895.91. If you sum these numbers you should get 117095.51 but when i add them together and put into the database, the result is 117095.5 which is wrong because last "1" digit is missing.

Comment: @Dave thank you Dave, it really helped me. This was the right solution. Im glad. We can close the topic here.